# Books about Riemannian differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

Can someone recommend me some books for "beginners" about "Riemannian differential geometry"? As well, with exercises and solutions.
Thank you!

Comment: 'Riemannian Geometry' by Gallot et al is a good beginner book and includes solutions to its exercises. It assumes working knowledge of smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

I think Morgan's is the most "elementary" text on Riemannian Geometry (and it includes exercises and solutions to some of them). Gallot et al. as well as Godinho & Natário are a bit more advanced (also with problems and solutions). Finally, at a more advanced level, you can take a look at Sakai's book which is excellent.